# Criar verificar múltiplos valores de uma variável

Tags: php

Tenho um conjunto de regras que esta ocupando muito espaço no meu código:

```
if      ($ni == '1' && $status2 == 'Aberto'  ){
$url_edit = "<a href='edit_os.php?id1=$id1'>";

}elseif ($ni == '1' && $status2 == 'Em Andamento'){
$url_edit = "<a href='edit_os.php?id1=$id1'>";
```

e vai embora com várias dessas...

**Eu queria era algo do tipo:**

```
if ($ni == 1 && status2 = LISTA DE PALAVRAS)
```

Então, se nível for igual a 1 e status for igual a algumas palavra na lista, entra no `if`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso colocando a lista de palavras numa array, e verificando se o valor da variável está contido na lista, com [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
$statusPermitidos = array('Aberto', 'Em Andamento');
if ($ni == '1' && in_array($status2, $statusPermitidos)) {
    // ...
}
```